# Schema error while trying to upload a WSDL

Tags: webservices

I'm trying to upload the following wsdl to generate apex classes.But i'm getting a schema error Do I need to make any changes on the xsd?

Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Found schema import from location https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/xsd/platform/v2015_1_0/core.xsd. External schema import not supported

Comment: What's the complete error?

Comment: https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2015_1_0/netsuite.wsdl

Answer (score 2):

The Salesforce tooling only supports a sub-set of the possible constructs available in WSDL/XSD. See [SOAP Services: Defining a Class from a WSDL Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm) for the details.

One thing not supported is the external schema import your WSDL contains. That can potentially by manually fixed by you editing the files: grab the source of the imports and add themin-line. The example in the documentation of such a fix is to convert this:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema
   elementFormDefault="qualified"
   targetNamespace="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="AmazonS3.xsd"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

to this:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema
    xmlns:tns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">

    <xsd:element name="CreateBucket">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
   [...]
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Unfortunately your WSDL contains a lot of imports.

There is also a pretty hight chance that you will run into other unsupported features.

Comment: <xsd:import namespace="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" schemaLocation="https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/xsd/platform/v2015_1_0/core.xsd"/>                                        Can you pls help me on the conversion of this import I'm confused on how to handle the name space and schem alocation.

Comment: @HarishGudipudi I can't access that... Roughly speaking you need to setup the namespace prefixes used in the XSD on the xsd:schema element.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Salesforce only supports very basic WSDL features and the WSDL 2 Apex tool isn't very helpful for most WSDLs.

I've had some decent success using [FuseIt SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/products/fuseit-sfdc-explorer/)'s WSDL Parser & Apex Generate Features.  You may be interested in looking into it and seeing if it better meets your needs.