# WSDL2Apex: How to edit Paypal WSDL because of few XSD schema imports?

Tags: apex, soap-api, wsdl2apex, paypal

Please help me edit Paypal WSDL because of its XSD schema imports. I needed to run it over to WSDL2Apex of Salesforce. And with import, it would return an error:

> Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Found schema import from location CoreComponentTypes.xsd. External schema import not supported

I've found a good workaround through this answer: [Schema error while trying to upload a WSDL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79957/schema-error-while-trying-to-upload-a-wsdl/79961#79961) but I don't know how to do it with the following files below and I need assistance.

If you will look at [Paypal SOAP API docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture/#paypal-wsdlxsd-schema-definitions), you will see that it requires eBay Business Language (eBL) base and core components:

> The PayPal Web Services schema and its underlying eBay Business Language (eBL) base and core components are required for developing applications with the PayPal Web Services API.

Please help me integrate the eBL base and core components into Paypal WSDL. Here are the files:

- PayPal Schema: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl
- eBL Base Components and Component Types: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/eBLBaseComponents.xsd https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/CoreComponentTypes.xsd

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=wsdl%20external%20schema

Comment: @Eric, sir, I've already searched the result and I've found out that none was clear, and just gave broad answer. And so I've decided to ask for a specific question sir, which focuses specifically with the Paypal SOAP API and the imports of the required XSD

Comment: Answer is not specific to PayPal API. External schema is essentially not supported by sf and anything you find is sn attempt at a workaround. PayPal has a rest API correct? If so I would use that.

Comment: Yes sir @Eric, unfortunately, I cannot ask for clarification in this answer: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79957/schema-error-while-trying-to-upload-a-wsdl/79961#79961 because I'm new here and my reputation is way below 50.

Comment: The answer does not change. If you have a question about the answer narrow your question to what you really want to ask and link to that answer in the post

Comment: Oh yeah, you are @Eric, I'll update the question and the description now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting WSDL that presents a number of challenges to import into Salesforce.

I've been able to generate the Apex classes for it using the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer Wsdl2Apex](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) functionality (Disclosure: This is a free tool made publicly available by my current employer).

I needed to make a number of modifications to get it to generate correctly:

1. Download and save a local version of https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl
2. Download and save a local version of https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/EnhancedDataTypes.xsd
3. In the WSDL, modify the import statements to have the full path to the XSDs. Use the local file path for EnhancedDataTypes.xsd

   ```
   <import namespace="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" schemaLocation="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/CoreComponentTypes.xsd"/>
   <import namespace="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" schemaLocation="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/eBLBaseComponents.xsd"/>
   <import namespace="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" schemaLocation="C:\Users\IAmAFish\Documents\EnhancedDataTypes.xsd"/>
   ```
4. Modify EnhancedDataTypes.xsd to comment out the unsupported elements under the EnhancedPaymentDataType complexType. Basically everything from the opening annotation to the closing sequence. The annotation and sequence throw all sorts of errors around "The 'annotation' element is not supported in this context"

Here is the output I generated:

- [ebayApiPaypalapi.cls](https://gist.github.com/FishOfPrey/9eb7ca7dbb7241b0e14e18a2034e45ba)
- [ebayApisCorecomponenttypes.cls](https://gist.github.com/FishOfPrey/b7ddffc45a6193194a40a8052bbd5d78)
- [ebayApisEblbasecomponents.cls](https://gist.github.com/FishOfPrey/fab2e87de0e57dba043e2bcf21e1a72d)
- [ebayApisEnhanceddatatypes.cls](https://gist.github.com/FishOfPrey/f1eb0682c74ce1b7a9ddc37653557f83)

Comment: Wow! Thank you @daniel-ballinger ! Did you know that yesterday, I've downloaded the very essential FuseIT SFDC Explorer Wsdl2Apex and tried it and it's very COOL! I've also come up with exchanging the the `schemalocation` of `import` to it's links but I haven't done the commenting of `annotation` (giggle). Thank you so much! Many developers have been looking for a solution to this.

Comment: And oh, guys looking for this solution, make sure you have the latest FuseIT SFDC Explorer Wsdl2Apex

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri Yes, sorry. Forgot to mention that this will need to latest build [(3.3)](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/09/fuseit-sfdc-explorer-33162747.html) I did today to support a local file path schemaLocation. Glad it helped!

Comment: And also, it looks like ebayApiPaypalapi.cls is truncated. However, I was able to generate full of it using the tools. Thanks again.